# Number of ways of decomposing the graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The book by Narsingh Deo defines the decomposition of a graph into two subgraphs as follows:

> A graph $G$ is said to be decomposed into two subgraphs $g_1$ and $g_2$ if
>   $$g_1 \cup g_2 = G$$
>   and
>   $$g_1 \cap g_2 = \text{a null graph}$$
>   where the null graph is one without any edges.
>   In other words, every edge of G occurs either in $g_1$ or in $g_2$, but not in both. Some of the vertices, however, may occur in both $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Finally it states that

> A graph containing $m$ edges can be decomposed in $2^{m-1}-1$ different ways into pairs of subgraphs.

Number of ways to obtain two subgraphs should equal to $\binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{2}+...+\binom{m}{m-1}$ since $\binom{m}{0}$ and $\binom{m}{m}$ will result in selecting the whole original graph and not decomposing it at all.

I know $\binom{m}{0}+\binom{m}{1}+...+\binom{m}{m}=2^m$

So the number of ways to obtain two subgraphs should equal to $2^m-2$. So what I am missing? How it is $2^{m-1}-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide by 2 because the order of the two graphs doesn't matter.  For example, you decompose into subgraphs $A$ and $B$; it is the same as if you decompose into $B$ and $A$.

The best way to think of it is by colorings; you want to color all the edges using red and blue.  But if you consider the red and blue edges as separate subgraphs and ignore the color, it doesn't matter if you take the red edges as subgraph $A$ and the blue ones as subgraph $B$, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Decomposition of the graph can be seen as dividing the graph $G$ into mutually exclusive subgraphs.

1. The total number of possible subgraphs of a graph $G$ with $m$ edges is $2^m$.
2. Total number of mutually exclusive pairs is $2^{m−1}$.
3. But mutually exclusive pair $(0, m)$ is not a decomposition.

Therefore, total number of possible decompositions is $2^{m-1} -1$.